# Azure MSSQL Server slow ingestion

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-elasticpool

I am trying to ingest 9,000,000 rows in an elastic pool database with 6 Vcore. Data ingestion using python (pyodbc).

Since data is large, I am ingesting the data in chunks.

I am getting weird behaviour after the 9th chunk of the ingestion. Process disappear and randomly appears after an hour.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: can you give a screenshot or any concrete example of this "weird behavior"?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion use [non-durable memory-optimized table](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/in-memory-oltp-in-azure-sql-database/#:%7E:text=A%20non-durable%20table%20is%20a%20memory-optimized%20table%20that,for%20cases%20where%20durability%20is%20not%20a%20concern.) to speed up data ingestion, while managing the In-Memory OLTP storage footprint by offloading historical data to a disk-based Columnstore table. Use a job to regularly batch-offload data to a disk-based Columnstore table.

With that adjustment you can obtain 1.4 million sustained rows per second during ingestion.

Comment: Why do you **bold all your links?** Please don't. Generally speaking, linking is enough to draw users' attention to things.